# Perl Print function does not work properly when Sleep() is used

Tags: perl

I have the following code to print a "." each second to simulate a progress bar.

```
$num = 15;
while($num--){
    sleep(1);
    print ".";
}
```

The problem I'm having now is the "." character is not printed after each loop. Instead, all 15 "." are printed at once after the loop exits. However if I print ".\n", it works fine. But the "." will be printed on a new line every time which is not what I want.

It seems quite weird and could not figure out why. Could anyone provide some help? Thank you.

Regards,
Allen

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That's probably because I/O is being buffered. Try disabling buffering (autoflush):

```
$| = 1;
```

before your loop.

For a more complete explanation, refer to [How do I flush/unbuffer an output filehandle? Why must I do this?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-flush%2funbuffer-an-output-filehandle%3f--Why-must-I-do-this%3f)

Comment: Thank you Mat, this works great! I will have a read of the article you recommended. I'm amazed by the rapidity of the answering of my question. I was expecting to get an answer before I go to bed tonight.

Answer (score 4):

You need to disable buffering on STDOUT.  See [`$|` in perlfaq](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-flush/unbuffer-an-output-filehandle?--Why-must-I-do-this?)

Comment: Thank you @aschepler , after disabling buggering, it works fine.

Comment: One should always disable buggering at the top of every Perl script.

Answer (score 1):

The standard output stream is usually buffered. Try flushing the output stream after each print statement. See the [Perl Cookbook, §7.13](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch07_13.htm) for a detailed explanation and solution.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation Philip. Buffering is indeed the problem.

Comment: Please don't link to pirated content